# Textboxes change height and border width after javascript alert

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, textbox

I have these textboxes:

```
<asp:Label ID="lbllastname" runat="server" Text="LastName" 
     CssClass="labels" />&nbsp;
<asp:TextBox ID="txtlastname" runat="server" CssClass="texts"
     onkeyup="firstElementPress(event);" TabIndex="3" />
<br />
<asp:Label ID="lblfirstname" runat="server" Text="FirstName" 
     CssClass="labels" />&nbsp;
<asp:TextBox ID="txtfirstname" runat="server" CssClass="texts"
      onkeyup="firstElementPress(event);" TabIndex="4" />
<br />
<asp:Label ID="lblmi" runat="server" Text="MI" CssClass="labels" />&nbsp;
<asp:TextBox ID="txtmi" runat="server" CssClass="texts"
      onkeyup="firstElementPress(event);" TabIndex="5" />
<br />
<asp:Label ID="lblext" runat="server" Text="Suffix" CssClass="labels" />&nbsp;
<asp:TextBox ID="txtext" runat="server" CssClass="texts"
     onkeyup="firstElementPress(event);" TabIndex="6" />
```

CSS:

```
.labels
{
    font: bold 10pt Calibri;
    color: Black;
}

.texts
{
    border-color: Black;
    border-width: thin;
    height: 16px;
    font: 10pt Calibri;
}
```

They're fine but if the user encounters the javascript alert when the name already exists, these textboxes lose their height and the border thickens. I have no idea why this is happening.

Here's the code for the alert:

```
Response.Write("<script>alert('The name you specified already exists!');
                </script>");
```

Why is this happening? I don't think it has something to do with the javascript on the `onkeyup` event. Or maybe it does? IDK. It just places the focus on different controls.

In any case, here's the Javascript for it:

```
function firstElementPress(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        document.getElementById('fuso').focus();
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 17) {
        document.getElementById('txtso').focus();
    }
}
```

I wish someone would explain to me why this happens. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this... :

Prompt message as like below :

```
 Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alertmesg", "<script language=javascript> alert('The name you specified already exists!');</script>");
```

against

```
Response.Write("<script>alert('The name you specified already exists!');</script>");
```

Thank you...

Comment: Omfg it worked! Thank you for that. But can you explain to me why all those textboxes behaved that way when I was using the Response.Write alert? It really baffled me so I want to understand why it happens.